# Indexing list of tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have two identical lists of tensors (with different sizes) except that for the first one all of the tensors are assigned to the cuda device. For example:

```
list1=[torch.tensor([0,1,2]).cuda(),torch.tensor([3,4,5,6]).cuda(),torch.tensor([7,8]).cuda()]
>>> list1
[tensor([0, 1, 2], device='cuda:0'), tensor([3, 4, 5, 6], device='cuda:0'), tensor([7, 8], device='cuda:0')]
```

```
list2=[torch.tensor([0,1,2]),torch.tensor([3,4,5,6]),torch.tensor([7,8])]
>>> list2
[tensor([0, 1, 2]), tensor([3, 4, 5, 6]), tensor([7, 8])]
```

I want to extract some tensors from the lists according to an array of indices such as:

```
ind=torch.tensor([0,2])
>>> ind
tensor([0, 2])
```

So my solution was to do something like that:

```
np.array(list1)[ind]
```

```
np.array(list2)[ind]
```

My question is why it works with the first list with the tensors defined on the cuda device and gives an error with the second list as shown below:

```
>>> np.array(list1)[ind]
array([tensor([0, 1, 2], device='cuda:0'),
       tensor([7, 8], device='cuda:0')], dtype=object)
```

```
>>> np.array(list2)[ind]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

---

EDIT:
Just to clarify, the error isn't raised because the tensors have different shapes. The following examples illustrate this point:

```
list3=[torch.tensor([1,2,3]).cuda()]
list4=[torch.tensor([1,2,3]).cuda(),torch.tensor([4,5,6]).cuda()]
list5=[torch.tensor([1,2,3])]
list6=[torch.tensor([1,2,3]),torch.tensor([4,5,6])]
```

And the results are:

```
>>> np.array(list3)
array([tensor([1, 2, 3], device='cuda:0')], dtype=object)
>>> np.array(list4)
array([tensor([1, 2, 3], device='cuda:0'),
       tensor([4, 5, 6], device='cuda:0')], dtype=object)
>>> np.array(list5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
>>> np.array(list6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.array` trys to convert each of the elements of a list into a numpy array. This is only supported for CPU tensors. The short answer is you can explicitly instruct numpy to create an array with `dtype=object` to make the CPU case works. To understand what exactly is happening lets take a closer look at both cases.

#### Case 1 (CUDA tensors)

First note that if you attempt to use `np.array` on a CUDA tensor you get the following error

```py
np.array(torch.zeros(2).cuda())
```

```
TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

In your example, numpy tries to convert each element of `list1` to a numpy array, however an exception is raised so it just settles on creating an array with `dtype=object`.

You end up with

```py
np.array([torch.tensor([0,1,2]).cuda(), torch.tensor([3,4,5,6]).cuda(), torch.tensor([7,8]).cuda()])
```

being just a container pointing to different objects

```
array([tensor([0, 1, 2], device='cuda:0'),
       tensor([3, 4, 5, 6], device='cuda:0'),
       tensor([7, 8], device='cuda:0')], dtype=object)
```

#### Case 2 (CPU tensors)

For CPU tensors, PyTorch knows how to convert to numpy arrays. So when you run

```py
np.array(torch.zeros(2))
```

you get a numpy array with dtype `float32`

```
array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

The problem comes in your code when numpy successfully converts each element in `list2` into a numpy array and then tries to stack them into a single multi-dimensional array. Numpy expects that each list entry represents one row of a multi-dimensional array, but in your case it finds that not all rows have the same shape, so doesn't know how to proceed and raises an exception.

One way to get around this is to explicitly specify that dtype should remain `object`. This basically tells numpy "don't try to convert the entries to numpy arrays first".

```
np.array([torch.tensor([0,1,2]), torch.tensor([3,4,5,6]), torch.tensor([7,8])], dtype=object)
```

which now gives a similar result to case 1

```
array([tensor([0, 1, 2]),
       tensor([3, 4, 5, 6]),
       tensor([7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. For the second part, I don't think that it raises the exception because the shapes are different so it cannot stack as it fails also if they all have the same shape. Also, it fails in case that the list has only one tensor i.e. np.array([torch.zeros(2)]). I still cannot get this behavior.

Comment: Interesting, i can confirm your finding. This seems to imply that numpy is attempting to convert to a scalar at some point. I'm not super familiar with the numpy C source code where this conversion takes place, but I'll take a look and see if i can track down exactly why this is happening. That said, specifying dtype=object still seems to be the solution if you're looking to use numpy for indexing. Though I would argue that in most numpy is completely unnecessary here since you could just use normal python list comprehension to select a subset of a list and that will be easier to interpret.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with dtype=object and it works well and I agree that the selection can be done in different ways but I am trying to understand why this behavior is happening. Thanks again.